# Horizontal menu not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blogengine.net

I'm using BlogEngine.NET 2.0 with the boldy theme (can be seen [here](http://rtur.net/blog/default.aspx)). But when I add a page to a parent page let's say

```
foo
|-> bar
```

If I mouse over foo, bar doesn't appear (they both are published).

I know that it's a precise topic, but I'm looking for help!

How can I make the submenu appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely missed item #3 in the ReadMe file:

1. Copy “Bodly” folder into the /themes folder
2. Copy PageMenu.cs into /app_code/controls folder
3. Add script reference to the admin/settings/tracking scripts:

`<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="/blog/js.axd?path=/blog/themes/Boldy/js/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>`

*** remove "/blog" if your site is in the root or replace with your site name if it is not "blog" but something else

Comment: An answer from the creator of the theme, nice! Thank you, I'll try this later at home :)